# How to select a range of cells in Excel based on a condition?

Tags: excel, vba

I need to select the demand range in sheet 1 corresponding to the part number selected in Sheet 2 of my workbook. So far, I have written the macro to automatically select the part number in sheet 1 when the same part number is selected in sheet no 2. But, I'm having trouble selecting the range corresponding to the part number, which I want to base my calculations on. Can anyone please tell me how to select the range?

```
Public Sub calculation()
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim findcell As Range
    Dim a_1 As Range
    Dim b_1 As Range
    Dim rnge As Range

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
    x = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").Value
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A26")        

    For Each i In rng
        If x = i Then
            Set findcell = i
        End If
    Next i

    j = findcell.Select

    Set a_1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
    Set b_1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 66)

    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C9").Value "=AVERAGE(Sheet1!"a_1.Address":"b_1.Address")"
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Should be able to do something like this:

```
Public Sub calculation()

    Dim f As Range

    Set f = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A26").Find( _
               what:=Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C3").Value, _
               lookat:=xlWhole)

    With Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C9")
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            .Formula = "=AVERAGE(Sheet1!" & f.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, 66).Address & ")"
        Else
            .Value = "???"
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This really helps a lot. I just started VBA yesterday and it hasn't been easy. If you don't mind, can you also tell me how can I plot a line chart for the selected range simultaneously when the user select the part numbers? So basically, every time the user selects a new part number, the line graph will change based on the range. Also, is there a way to clear all calculated parameters and plots when the user selects a new part number?